# Paramiko to list SAS Jobs(PYTHON)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Good morning.  So I'm stuck on this problem for work.  Using the Paramiko library I'm trying to automate the simple task that a lot of people do at work for DB2 instances.  I already had one job set up to reset a bunch of passwords so i know the basics of connecting to the server are correct its just a matter of these commands are not doing what I want.  What I'm trying to do is after the second command of "bjobs" I want to be able view the output.  I've tried using stdout.read() and so far its not giving me anything but b''.  Any help is very needed.

```
from paramiko import client
from os import getlogin

class ssh:
client = None

def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    print("Connecting to server")
    self.client = client.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password)
    print("Connected to " + address)

def sendCommand(self, command):
    if(self.client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        x= stdout.read()
        print(x)
        while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata+=stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                print(str(alldata, 'utf8'))
    else:
        print("connection not opened")


serverCon = "My Server"
plist = []
currPass = 'MyPassword!'

#get user information
userName = getlogin()

#Connect to server, insert and chnage passwords

connection = ssh(serverCon, userName, currPass)
connection.sendCommand(r'. /opt/sas/lsf/conf/profile.lsf')

connection.sendCommand('bjobs')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `exec_command()` would execute the command with a new instance of shell (the user's *login shell* on the ssh server) so your first `. /opt/sas/lsf/conf/profile.lsf` would not affect the following `bjobs`. You should write

```
exec_command('. /opt/sas/lsf/conf/profile.lsf; bjobs')
```

which is basically the same as

```
ssh user@host '. /opt/sas/lsf/conf/profile.lsf; bjobs'
```

---

According to the manual:

> **class paramiko.client.SSHClient**
>
> > `exec_command(command, bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False)`
> >
> > Execute a command on the SSH server. **A new Channel is opened** and the requested command is executed. The command’s input and output streams are returned as Python file-like objects representing
> >     stdin, stdout, and stderr.
>
> **class paramiko.channel.Channel**
>
> > `exec_command(*args, **kwds)`
> >
> > Execute a command on the server. If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly connected to the
> >     stdin, stdout, and stderr of the command being executed.
> >     **When the command finishes executing, the channel will be closed and can't be reused. You must open a new channel if you wish to execute another command.**

Comment: You have NO IDEA how much I love you right now.   Just trying to learn SSH and stuff so ya a bit of a new concept for me.  Never the less you rule.

Comment: you could take a look what's in `stderr.read()` and `recv_exit_status()` when you found something wrong.

Comment: I tried looking at stderr.read() and it was getting no values increasing my confusion or sometimes i would get b''.  I spent more time trying to figure this out than I would like to admit.